# Why missing \endcsname with phantom option in tikz-cd?

Tags: babel, tikz-cd, csname

Why does the following give at line 9 the error `Missing \endcsname inserted`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  f \arrow[d, phantom, ''\partial''] \\
  g
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

`"` not `''`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  f \arrow[d, phantom,"\partial"] \\
  g
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought that was the problem. But I didn't see how, in TeXShop, to get a double-quote instead of two single-quotes. When I copied the `"\partial"` from your answer and pasted it into my source, still I gotthe same problem. But when I copied your entire `tikzcd` environment and pasted into my document, no problem. So remains mysterious to me.

Comment: (Herb Schulz has now provided me with a TeXShop macro for typing a double-quote.)